# How accurate is Conky?

Tags: performance, conky

I'm on Crunchbang 64 bit, Conky shows that I'm using 4% of my CPU.

But I can feel the CPU burning so hot, got Spotify, Chrome and couple other apps running. On windows 7 chrome uses about half of the CPU, how come everything uses only 4% on Crunchbang (I'm using the same chrome version and same plugins and everything on Windows and Crunchbang), sometimes I see the CPU usage like 6% or 8%, even that is too low.

I know that Crunchbang is lightweight that's why I installed it but the numbers I'm seeing are hard to believe, something isn't right.

**Edit**

My [Conky.conf](http://pastebin.com/Af64fX76) and my [Conkyrc](http://pastebin.com/JWnTGEcb).

As of right now, CPU usage between 2% and 4%, CPU temp between 84 and 86 degrees Celsius. (Between 183 and 186 degrees Fahrenheit), I'm using `lm-sensors` to monitor the CPU temperature.

Comment: Can you provide your conky.conf file please? Most likely you're grabbing the wrong data regarding the CPU/System's temperature.

Comment: @slm I edited the question Sir.

Comment: Sounds like your issue isn't CPU usage or load, it just feels hot. Part of the answer is: that's laptops for you. The other bit is to give it a thorough vacuuming anyplace you can find an air inlet/outlet. 86°C is kinda hot and you want the cooling system to get as much air as it can. Alternatively, you can keep it immersed in liquid nitrogen, but it makes it a little hard to type that way.

Comment: Which one is giving you 4%? The `CPU Usage:$color $cpu%`from your conky.conf or the `CPU usage:$alignr${cpu cpu0}%` from conkyrc?  The two are different.

Comment: @terdon i think it's the one from conkyrc

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using the application `lm_sensors` to get your systems temperature readings. You can see the output by of this command with the command `sensors`.

For example:

```
$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +56.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        3815 RPM
temp1:        +56.0°C  
temp2:         +0.0°C  
temp3:         +0.0°C  
temp4:         +0.0°C  
temp5:         +0.0°C  
temp6:         +0.0°C  
temp7:         +0.0°C  
temp8:         +0.0°C
```

Setting it up can be tricky sometimes though.

#### Setup

Depending on your distro you'll likely have to give the command `apt-get install lm_sensors` or `yum install lm_sensors`.

Once installed it needs to be configured. You can use the tool provided to do this, `sensors-detect`. It's interactive (in a terminal) so you'll have to answer several questions to help it identify your system. This is usually the step that trips most people up, but give it a try.

#### Back to conky

Once you have `lm_sensors` installed and configured you can add lines like these to incorporate output from external commands into conky's display.

For example, say we want to grab the temperature from the sensor's command. This line from the output above:

```
temp1:        +56.0°C
```

This command will grab just the value:

```
$ sensors|grep temp1|tail -1|awk '{print $2}'
+56.0°C
```

To get `conky` to do this you'd add a line like this to your `.conf` file:

```
${execi 20 sensors |grep temp1|tail -1|awk '{print $2}'}
```

You can then incorporate the above line into your `.conf` file where ever you'd like the temperature to show up.

Comment: Those thinkpads have nice thermal design. I usually hit 66°C on my embarrassed-be-named-lappy running ondemand clock at 1/4 max clock.