# Conky: round ${top cpu 1}

Tags: conky

I have `${top cpu 1}` that show me for example `13.34`. Is it possible to round this to `13`?

Comment: I think it is not possible directly, but use `execi` to do something like [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87542/125388) as workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a small bit of `lua` code to do this for you. For example, in your `~/.conkyrc`:

```lua
conky.config = {
    lua_load = '/tmp/mylua.lua',
};
conky.text = [[
 ${lua conky_myfun ${top cpu 1}}
]]
```

and in file `/tmp/mylua.lua`

```lua
     function conky_myfun(arg)
      local n = conky_parse(arg)
      return math.floor(tonumber(n)+.5)
     end
```

This calls `conky_myfun` with the given arg. The function
evaluates the arg to get the value, it is converted to a number,
and rounded to the nearest integer.